# Problem with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I have a problem with getting my .htaccess to work like I want and I was wondering if anyone could shed a light on this.

Here is my current setup:

My shared hosting site can be accessed by http://www20.a2hosting.com/~myname/

I have several sub directories inside that I wish to access. For instance
http://www20.a2hosting.com/~myname/subdir/public/index.php works just fine.

Now I'm trying to get all the calls to my subdir/public be re-directed to my index.php and to that extent I've created a .htaccess file in my subdir/public that looks as following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

However, when I direct my browser to http://www20.a2hosting.com/~myname/subdir/public/
I get the following 404 Error:

```
The requested URL /home/myname/public_html/subdir/public/index.php was not found on this server.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you upload files, you do indeed upload them to `/home/myname/public_html/` right?

Comment: @Tim yeah, I can access the files just fine if directly enter them into the URL

Comment: @user: Ah, OK. I only asked because `mod_rewrite` will automatically expand `~myname` to a home directory, regardless of the `mod_userdir` settings, so I didn't know if that was in line with how your host had set things up.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am facing the exact same issue .

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying an absolute path as the rewrite target:

```
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php
```

Comment: I just tried that and it ended up re-directing me to some default a2hosting.com page that informed me that the page I must have been trying to access was my cPanel and gave me a link to that. Very strange.

Comment: @user strange. Then try `/home/myname/public_html/index.php`

Comment: @user sorry, then I don't know. But where is index.php? If it's in /myname, then you need to put it there.

Comment: no worries thanks for trying. I have a ticket open with their support staff so hopefully they'll be able to tell me what's wrong